# Can not implicitly convert type "Pottery_store.DataLayer.Domain.User" to "bool"

Tags: c#, service, repository, clean-architecture, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying to use clean architecture for my Project. for "Log in" part I made a method in repository that want to check is user exist wit this "email" and "password". now I faced with this error. please help me to solve this error and write true codes here. The Problem is "Is User Exist By This Email And Password" method.

```
using Pottery_store.DataLayer.Context;
using Pottery_store.DataLayer.Domain;
using Pottery_store.DataLayer.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Pottery_store.DataLayer.Repositories
{
    public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
        Pottery_storeDbContext _context;
        public UserRepository(Pottery_storeDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public int AddUser(User user)
        {
            _context.Users.Add(user);
            return user.UserId;
        }

        public void DeleteUser(int userId)
        {
            //_context.Remove(_context.Users.Where(x => x.UserId == userId));
            var user = GetUserById(userId);
            DeleteUser(user);
        }

        public void DeleteUser(User user)
        {
            // _context.Remove(_context.Users.Where(x => x.UserId == user.UserId));
            _context.Remove(user);
        }

        public void EditUser(User user)
        {
            _context.Users.Update(user);
        }

        public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
        {
            return _context.Users;
        }

        public User GetUserByActiveCode(string activeCode)
        {
            //return _context.Users.Find(activeCode);
            return _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.ActiveCode == activeCode);
        }

        public User GetUserById(int userId)
        {
            // return _context.Users.Find(x => x.UserId == userId);
            return _context.Users.Find(userId);
        }

        public bool IsEmailExist(string email)
        {
            return _context.Users.Any(u => u.Email == email);
        }

        public bool IsUserNameExist(string userName)
        {
            return _context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == userName);
        }

        **public bool IsUserExistByThisEmailAndPassword(string email, string password)
        {
            return _context.Users.SingleOrDefault
                   (u => u.Email == email && u.Password == password);
        }**

        public void Save()
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `return _context.Users.Any(u => u.Email == email && u.Password == password);`

Comment: `SingleOrDefault` returns the entity you are requesting, i.e. a `User`. `Any` is like SQL `EXISTS` and returns a bool.

Comment: @nilsK THANKS. error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for an exists you should probably just stick with `Any()`. If wanting to verify only one exists, compare your current result with `null`. Verifying only one exists brings up the issue of where that validation should occur and error thrown, but that is a separate conversation from your question.

## Exists

```
public bool IsUserExistByThisEmailAndPassword(string email, string password)
{
     return _context.Users.Any(u => u.Email == email && u.Password == password);
}
```

## Single

```
public bool IsUserExistByThisEmailAndPassword(string email, string password)
{
    var user = _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Email == email && u.Password == password);
    return user != null;
}
```